# Angular component need to be refresh after add data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

Very difficult to resolve that for me. I've a component who get Json data from 2 different url to create a chart:

- 1 update data is for the old values
- the other for the real time value

Here is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-staticchart',
  templateUrl: './staticchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./staticchart.component.scss']
})
export class StaticchartComponent implements OnInit {
  candles: Observable<Candlecollect[]>;
  data: Array<any>;
  candlecollect: Candlecollect;
  start = Date.now();
  end = Date.now() + 1;
 

  constructor(private candlecollectService: CandlecollectService,
              public spinnerService: SpinnerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadChart();
  }

  loadChart(): void {

    /*
    * Request to get the 500 latest Candlesticks - send by rest to the back api
    */
    const answer = this.candlecollectService.extractCandles('url_1')
      .subscribe(data => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
        for (let counter = 1; counter < 500; counter++) {

          candleSeries.update({
            // @ts-ignore
            time: data.openTime / 1000,
            open: data.open,
            high: data.high,
            low: data.low,
            close: data.close
          });
        }
      });

    /*
    * Request send by REST to get the real time values
    */
    const binanceSocket = new WebSocket('url_2');
    binanceSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
      // console.log(event.data);
      const candlestick = message.k;
      candleSeries.update({
        // @ts-ignore8
        time: candlestick.t / 1000,
        open: candlestick.o,
        high: candlestick.h,
        low: candlestick.l,
        close: candlestick.c
      });
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<mat-card class="dashboard-card">
  <div id="chart" fxFill></div>
</mat-card>
```

It works perfectly but I have this problem: I need to refresh the page or the chart doesn't appear.

So I've tried to put a SpinnerService to wait the loading but it doesn't works.

I'm sorry if this question seems stupid but I work with angular for 1 month and it's little bit complicated...^^

Comment: How does your html template look like?

Comment: I put it in the inital post but it's a very simple one. The chart is initialized in the <div class="chart">

Comment: i see a candleSeries and a fxFill directive. What are they doing?

Comment: the candleseries just add the data to the chart. The fxFill is a visual angular material property to adapt the content.

Comment: You have not bound any property of your component class to inside your template. Updating service data will not change your template unless you bind some variables inside your template

Comment: Never do something like that. Do you have an example please? Here is an example of a chart instantiated by javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/TradingView/eaod9Lq8/